# Control flow and loop: Why the output of the program is 0 and not 000?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i = 0, k;
    if (i == 0)
        goto label;
        for (k = 0;k < 3; k++)
        {
            printf("hi\n");
            label: k = printf("%03d", i);
        }
}
```

Can anybody explain how the output is 0 and not 000? When i run the program in devc++ it gives the output 000. But in most of the websites i found the right answer to be 0.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked for, but please dont use goto

Comment: There are many things useless in your code :  the loop `for`, the `if` statment. I tried 3 websites and they all gave me `000`

Comment: In my PC I get `000` which seems to be the right answer. Don't know what website you used, but stick to the reliable compilers, such as gcc

Comment: What websites? Some links please..

Comment: thank you for helping me out. here are few links which baffled me. 1) https://www.sanfoundry.com/touch-c-programming-questions-goto-labels/  refer ques #8 2)http://studyhelpzone.com/c-programming-questions-answers-goto-labels.html refer ques #8

Comment: Jumping into the middle of an uninitialized for loop is undefined behaviour... you can get anything.  Why do you post expressely bad code to ask a question about printf format specifiers?

Answer (score 3):

The output *should* be `000`. `%3d` will print two spaces if `i` is `0`: the `%03d` will print zeros instead of the spaces. The return value of `printf` is the number of characters that have been printed, so the loop that you've crashed into will terminate as `k < 3` will be `0`.

There's no *undefined behaviour* in the rather odd code you've presented. So if the leading two zeros are missing then the compiler and / or the runtime environment that you're using is defective.

Comment: thank you for clarifying. i just got confused as most of the websites including sanfoundry.com gave the same answer ('0'). Thought my compiler was faulty.

Comment: yes, it's U.B., as the execution of the for control statements is not defined when you have jump into the middle of an inner block from a goto statement.  You cannot ensure what the compiler will do, or the order it will execute the statements of the for loop since you have not passed to buy the ticket.

Answer (score 3):

The proper output is `000`.

The format specifier `%03d` contains the conversion specifier `d`, a field width of 3, and the flag `0`.  The `d` specifier means to print an `int`.  The field width of 3 means that the value will be printed in a field at least 3 characters wide.  The `0` flag means that any extra spaces in the field to print are padded on the left with a 0.

Any compiler that does not output this is non-conforming.

Comment: avoiding thr fact that jumping into the middle of an uninitialized loop is U.B. and bad code, either.

Comment: @LuisColorado There's no initialization being skipped in this case, so it's not UB.  It is still bad code though.

Comment: for _initialization_ I mean the first statement in the `for` loop and the condition evaluation.  Case they have side effects, they will not be executed.  Of course, in case there are local to block variables defined, it's not clear if space on the stack will be allocated for them, but anyway, no initialization would be made.